# Google lookup as a CID source in CID Superfecta module

Tags: asterisk

How can I add Google as a CID Source in the Asterisk CID Superfecta module? I recall it was a source in older versions, but seems to be removed?

Answer (score 0):

You can export cid source to google doc, after that create script which will read that once a hour and put into mysql.

Comment: I was referring to Google search results to translate CID to names

Comment: never head something like that, but you can use wget+some result parsing.